# Sum and skip rows pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to sum specific rows and columns on pandas but I have some issues. Below is my sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'STT':['1','2','2.1','2.1.1','2.2','2.3','2.4'],
                         'Number 1':[100,0,10,5,20,30,40],
                         'Number 2':[120,0,15,7,25,35,45]})
df.head(10)
```

Output as below:

```
STT Number 1    Number 2
0   1   100 120
1   2   0   0
2   2.1 10  15
3   2.1.1   5   7
4   2.2 20  25
5   2.3 30  35
6   2.4 40  45
```

I want to sum of `2` from `2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4` and skip `2.1.1`
I used below code to sum:

```
df.iloc[1,1] = df.iloc[2,1]+((df.iloc[4:7,1]).sum())
df.iloc[1,2] = df.iloc[2,2]+((df.iloc[4:7,2]).sum())
df.head()
```

Output as below:

```
    STT Number 1    Number 2
0   1   100 120
1   2   100 120
2   2.1 10  15
3   2.1.1   5   7
4   2.2 20  25
5   2.3 30  35
6   2.4 40  45
```

Actually it's output that I want, but I'm curious that is there anyway to make code shorter? If dataframe have 100 columns so I have to write 100 times of same code?

I tried this code: `df.iloc[1,1:2] = df.iloc[2,1:2]+((df.iloc[4:7,1:2]).sum())` but it didn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to sum over? `Number 1` and `Number 2` columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, to have an programmatic way, you could do:

```
cols = ['Number 1', 'Number 2']
df.loc[df['STT'].eq('2'), cols] = df.loc[df['STT'].str.fullmatch(r'2\.\d'), cols].sum().values
```

output:

```
     STT  Number 1  Number 2
0      1     100.0     120.0
1      2     100.0     120.0
2    2.1      10.0      15.0
3  2.1.1       5.0       7.0
4    2.2      20.0      25.0
5    2.3      30.0      35.0
6    2.4      40.0      45.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I changed your code a little bit:
`for col in df.columns[1:]:
    df.loc[df['STT'].eq('2'), col] = df.loc[df['STT'].str.fullmatch(r'2\.\d'), col].sum()`

and it's worked.

Answer (score 1):

You are close, only for select both columns need `1:3` instead `1:2`:

```
df.iloc[1,1:3] = df.iloc[2,1:3] + (df.iloc[4:7,1:3]).sum()
print (df)
     STT  Number 1  Number 2
0      1       100       120
1      2       100       120
2    2.1        10        15
3  2.1.1         5         7
4    2.2        20        25
5    2.3        30        35
6    2.4        40        45
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's worked but it is not easy to control  I think.

Comment: @hoatran - I understand question `iloc` is requirement, seems not ;)

Comment: I said  it not easy to control because of last columns or rows number. For Example:
`import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'STT':['1','2','2.1','2.1.1','2.2','2.3','2.4','3','3.1','3.1.1','3.2','3.3','3.4'],
                         'Number 1':[100,0,10,5,20,30,40,0,15,5,22,37,43],
                         'Number 2':[120,0,15,7,25,35,45,0,17,5,25,39,47]})
df.iloc[1,1:3] = df.iloc[2,1:3] + (df.iloc[4:7,1:3]).sum()
df.iloc[7,1:3] = df.iloc[8,1:3] + (df.iloc[10:13,1:3]).sum()`

`df.iloc[4:7` and `df.iloc[7,` have the same 7.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use regex as what follows:

```py
df[df["STT"].str.contains("^2(\.\d)?$")]
```

##### Output

|  | STT | Number 1 | Number 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2.1 | 10 | 15 |
| 4 | 2.2 | 20 | 25 |
| 5 | 2.3 | 30 | 35 |
| 6 | 2.4 | 40 | 45 |

Then, if you are interested in summing over the `Number1` and `Number2` columns you can use:

```py
df[df["STT"].str.contains("^2(\.\d)?$")][["Number 1", "Number 2"]].sum()
```

##### Output

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| Number 1 | 100 |
| Number 2 | 120 |